# How would you transform [0,3,2,1] to ["three","three","three", "two","two","one"] in Swift 5?

Tags: swift

I am attempting to solve an issue in an app I am building.

I have gotten as far as filtering through and removing the zero, but I am unable to figure out how to duplicate the array values according to their Int value inside the array.

```
var array1: [Int] = [0,3,2,1]

let aboveZero = array1.filter{$0 >= 1}
print(aboveZero) // "[3, 2, 1]"

let words1 = aboveZero.map { NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: $0 as NSNumber, number: .spellOut) }
print(words1) // "["three", "two", "one"]"
```

Expected: "["three","three","three", "two","two","one"]"

Comment: Duplicate the values before converting the numbers to strings. That will make it much easier.

Comment: @matt Where has this been done before (link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flatMap` together with `Array.init(repeating:,count:)`:

```swift
[0, 3, 2, 1].flatMap {
    repeatElement(
        NumberFormatter.localizedString(
            from: $0 as NSNumber,
            number: .spellOut
        ),
        count: $0
    )
}
```

Comment: You can also use `repeatElement(_:count:)` which does not create intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array1: [Int] = [0,3,2,1]

let aboveZero = array1.filter{$0 >= 1}
print(aboveZero)

var array2: [Int] = []
aboveZero.forEach({ for _ in 0..<$0 { array2.append($0) } })
print(array2) // ["three", "three", "three", "two", "two", "one"]

let words1 = array2.map { NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: $0 as NSNumber, number: .spellOut) }
print(words1) // ["three", "three", "three", "two", "two", "one"]
```